# Clear cache for static website upon deploy with Heroku?

Tags: css, github, heroku, browser-cache

I have a static website hosted with Heroku's hobby tier. I have an issue where everytime I push a new deployment from my GitHub repository, my stylesheet doesn't update for hours (even though my HTML does). As the stylesheet displays correctly on an incognito tab and after clearing "Cached Images and Files," I assume locally cached website files are the issue. Is there a way to bypass this in order to update my CSS stylesheet after every deploy?

My stylesheet is ~600 lines if it matters.

Comment: You need to refresh you browser every time you update you CSS file `Chrome:

Option 1: Hold down Ctrl and click the Reload button (Windows) or Shift and click the Reload button (Mac)
Option 2: Hold down Ctrl and press F5 (Windows) or Cmd and Shift and R (Mac)`

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to my `htaccess` file worked for me.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
  FileETag None
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 12 Jan 1980 05:00:00 GMT"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

This prevents caching for HTML, HTM, JS, and CSS files.